# Is there a way of sending/receiving SMS(s) from a Huawei B315 LTE Router with PHP?

Tags: php

I tried to access the router's interface with curl but I am a new coder and I struggled to make this happen.

```
<?php 
$data = array( "User name" => "admin", "password" => "*****", "form" => "submit" ); 
// Initialized the cURL session with Target URL 
$ch = curl_init("192.168.8.1"); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, "true"); // Allow redirections 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true); // We are making a post request 
/*curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);*/ 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt'); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, "true");
$result = curl_exec($ch); 
curl_close($ch); 
echo $result; 
?>
```

Comment: It would help if you show what you have tried so far and where you are stuck with it.

Comment: <?php 


 $data = array(
  "User name" => "admin",
  "password" => "*****",
  "form" => "submit"

 );



  // Initiazed the cURL session with Target URL
  $ch = curl_init("http://192.168.8.1");
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, "true"); // Allow redirections
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true); // We are making a post request
  /*curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);*/
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt');
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, "true");

  $result = curl_exec($ch);
  curl_close($ch);

  echo $result;
  
 
 ?>

Comment: Tried the above with a google page, opens successfully, however it does not open  the router interface

Comment: Please use the [edit] button. Comments are not the place for essential things.

Comment: Does the router expose any kind of API or other (non-HTTP) interface designed for machine to machine interaction? That would be a better option. Trying to automate a web GUI is always tricky, especially when authentication is involved as well. Anyway, we haven't got enough info to answer the question. We don't know what this router interface looks like, so we can't whether you have called it correctly. And you havent told us what goes wrong - you say it doesn't "open", but what happens instead? What response do you get from the cURL request?

Answer (score 0):

I know this answer is a few years late, but for anyone still searching for answers to this, there is a PHP script on Github that allows for sending and receiving SMS via the Huawei-B315s-22 HTTP API. See https://github.com/Zili0/Huawei-B315s-22

I noticed that it calls the following endpoints:

```
/api/webserver/SesTokInfo
/api/user/state-login
/api/monitoring/status
/api/user/authentication_login
/api/device/information
/api/net/current-plmn
/api/monitoring/traffic-statistics
/api/sms/sms-count
/api/sms/sms-list
/api/wlan/multi-basic-settings
/api/device/control
/api/user/logout
```

There's also two other similar scripts I found, both written in Python that do similar things. Hopefully one of these will provide the kind of thing you need:

- https://github.com/shaan1337/huawei_b315s22_sms
- https://github.com/chenwei791129/Huawei-LTE-Router-SMS-to-E-mail-Sender